# Vb.net OLEDB Provider cannot be found

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, oledb, adodb

Trying to connect to SharePoint using VB.net , every time I try to open the connection string it gives the attached exception , I tried to changed the CPU in project properties from 64-bit to 32-bit , but its still the same error
Note: I tried this code on VBA with the exact connection string and it worked  , please help

```
With cnt
        .ConnectionString =
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;WSS;IMEX=1;RetrieveIds=Yes;DATABASE=http://*****;LIST={*****};"
        .Open
    End With
```

Comment: Sorry for missing the attachment , the exception says : 

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.'

Comment: Just [edit] it into the actual question.